# Printing to a file in Fortran suddenly stops at an if condition

Tags: fortran, physics

I'm currently trying to write to a Fortran 77 file that write 2000000 values to a left hand column of a file. Code is below:

```
    program signal

    integer dtq, dtb, dtt, mdotb, i, mdot
    real*4 mdotq, mdott, nmdott

    mdotb = 1       !burst phase
    mdotq = 0.001   !quiescent phase
    dtb = 100       !time for burst phase
    dtq = 1080      !time for quiescent phase
    dtt = 200       !transition time
    t = 0           !start time
    dt = 10         !time step
    n = 2000000     !interval
    t_startb = 0    !start of the range

    open(unit=1, file='accretion.txt',status='unknown')

    do i = 1, n

     dt_start = t-t_start
     t = t + dt
     mdott = ((0.999/200)*t) + 0.505
     nmdott = ((-0.999/200)*t) + 0.505

     if (dt_start .lt. dtb) then

      write(1,*) t, mdotb

     else if (dt_start .lt. dtt) then

      write(1,*) t, nmdott

     else if (dt_start .lt. dtq) then

      write(1,*) t, mdotq

     else if (dt_start .lt. dtt) then

      write(1,*) t, mdott

     endif

    enddo

    close(1)

    end
```

This only prints numbers up to 1080 so if stops at the third conditional which doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Do I have to write a label to the start of the loop to make it run again? Or is there syntax I've done wrong?

Comment: Insert the line `implicit none` immediately after the line `program signal` and fix the errors that the compiler identifies.

Comment: Do what Mark says and use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. And do not use Fortran 77 for new code in the 21st century.

Comment: Technically, real*4 comes from a vendor-specific non-standard Fortran 66.  It's even possible that this is responsible for some problems you would catch by implicit none (which takes you forward to 25 years ago).

Answer (score 1):

As people suggested before use the `implicit none` statement right after the `program signal`. You can find more information [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/6j4m0vn9v/index.html). I know that FORTRAN lacks a descent IDE, so check your code twice before asking for help. Only by a quick look I can see a duplicated else if statement and a typo.

Edit: use better conditions in if statements. Right now, there are cases where many of them are true simultaneously. Try something like `if (x .lt. y .and. x.ge.z) then`

Comment: Welcome, you are welcome to answer this or any other question. But do not just repeat the comment about a thing that will help to find the error. When you choose to write an answer you should write what is the actual error.

Comment: I don't know what you expect from a IDE to be "decent", but all of [Code::Blocks](http://cbfortran.sourceforge.net), [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fortran), [VS Code](https://github.com/krvajal/vscode-fortran-support), [Sublime](https://github.com/315234/SublimeFortran), [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/photran/) and [Visual Studio](https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compilers/details) have: syntax highlight, snippets, intellisence, refactoring, debugger, symbols table, error checking, auto compilation, context searches, peek declaration...

Comment: VladimirF TY for the feedback. I cannot see a better way to add information about implicit none without repeating part or the whole comment. I am sure that I did not just repeat it though. I tried to answer in a way that the OP would track his errors alone. I will try my best next time!
RodrigoRodrigues I think that FORTRAN is lacking in developer tools. I have not to this day used a text editor or an IDE whose tools would be equal for FORTRAN and ie.Python.

Comment: Definitely, Fortran needs more devtools; it is not mainstream enough to motivate many people to do it (narrow market/visibility), and also there isn't as much sharing in our community as there is with some other languages. Plus, many old-school "Macho" Fortran hackers disregard those fancy hippie ide features, and just stick to good' ol punchcards.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from some syntax errors (like the line that only says `t_start`, which is not valid Fortran) and some other comments present in the other answers and comments (lack of `implicit none`, non-standard kind declaration), there is a problem in the logic of your conditionals.

Suppose the `do` loop reached the iteration in which `dt_start=1090`, what happens then?

```
! dtb = 100, so this branch is skipped
if (dt_start .lt. dtb) then
  write(1,*) t, mdotb

! dtt = 200, so this branch is skipped
else if (dt_start .lt. dtt) then
  write(1,*) t, nmdott

! dtt = 200, so this branch is skipped (and it's repeated, by the way)
else if (dt_start .lt. dtt) then
  write(1,*) t, nmdott

! dtq = 1080, so this branch is skipped ALSO
else if (dt_start .lt. dtq) then
  write(1,*) t, mdotq

! dtt = 200, so this branch is skipped (repeated, AGAIN!)
else if (dt_start .lt. dtt) then
  write(1,*) t, mdott

endif
! nothing was done this iteration, continue to the next
```

So, your `do` loop is indeed running up to `n=2000000`, but it does nothing after `dt_start=1090`. Please, take your time to rethink the logic of your code and also to address the flaws pointed here.

Comment: The point of dt_start is to only reach 1080 then restart down to 0 again so that the loop will keep repeating the same interval over and over. I didn't program that in because I wanted it to print all the left column first. Also I am aware that the code isn't syntax accurate I copied my code and didn't cross check it with what i'd already written.

Comment: So, please edit the question to include the new information and any other that may be missing and would be relevant to the solution; and also to double check the syntax and make a working [mcve] so we can help you better